# How to prevent creating too many secrets in HashiCorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am looking for a better solution for secrets rotation and found Vault dynamic secrets is a good one. By enabling secrets engine, say to database, the applications / services can lease dynamic secrets.

I noticed every time the application to lease a database secret, Vault creates a new user / account in the DB. I understand, each application / service needs to be a good citizen and uses the secret as per the lease time. However, in a microservices environment, an implementation bug may cause the services to request too many dynamic secrets thus triggering to create too many accounts in the DB.

Is there any way to prevent creating too many accounts? I am just worrying too many accounts may cause problem in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You could go down the static roles which would created one role with a fixed user name and then vault would just rotate that password when it needs to be rotated.

Here are some docs to get you started

https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/databases#create-static-role
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases#static-roles

Also, a warning from the website:

> Not all database types support static roles at this time. Please
> consult the specific database documentation on the left navigation or
> the table below under Database Capabilities to see if a given database
> backend supports static roles.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using both Cassandra and Elasticsearch DBs which are not supporting static roles. So my question is still open - how Vault prevents generating too many accounts in the DBs if it only supports dynamic role?

Comment: You could fork cassandra and Elastic vault plugins and add the functionality for static roles in there your self. Im not sure i can see another way out without having 'static' creds (you could have a creds cache that all your apps have access to and rotate that once a day)

Comment: Yes, I believe technically it is possible to enable the cache and static role functionality with forking the vault plugin. However before doing that, I am really wondering as a product when Vault provided dynamic role, it is not a security / performance requirement for it to prevent numerous dynamic accounts?

Comment: i guess they preferred auditing reasons. If you have one user per call, you can trace the credentials and the user actions better. But thats my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I have the same understanding. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Can anyone of you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780065/vaults-static-role-or-dynamic-role-in-python