# Vault's Static role or Dynamic role in Python

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to implement database authentication for MongoDB using Vault. I decided to go with Static role as only one user per DB is needed and Vault rotates the user's password, but in case of Dynamic role every time when credentials are requested a new dynamic user is created.

My doubt is Java has something called [SecretLeaseContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/current/api/org/springframework/vault/core/lease/SecretLeaseContainer.html) which creates a new dynamic user only when the credentials of the previous dynamic user is expired. This is my understanding of Java's SecretLeaseContainer. Correct me if I am wrong.

But in Python's **hvac** library there is no such implementation like Java's SecretLeaseContainer. Is there any similar implementation in Python's **hvac** library like the afore mentioned Java's SecretLeaseContainer?

Comment: The question is currently unclear. In the first paragraph you explain the MongoDB static role and the dynamic users managed by Vault's MongoDB secrets engine in your setup. This is clear and correct. In the final paragraph, you ask how to switch from static users to dynamic users. This is unclear because your uses are already dynamic. Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard thanks for the suggestion, updated the question.

Comment: We are currently doing POC. Not sure which is better in production environment(Static or Dynamic roles)

Comment: After you generate the secret, it will have an associated TTL. You can perform lookups on the secret TTL to regenerate the secret after it expires. If this sounds ok, then I could probably demonstrate it in some code with the HVAC bindings.

Comment: yes @MattSchuchard currently hvac does not have that lookup option. Can you please help.

Comment: So actually HVAC does not have native bindings to the MongoDB secrets engine. It only supports the common/popular engines. You would need to use the generic logical in the bindings to return the secret, and then parse a generic secret object for its TTL accordingly. The code for that would be a bit beyond normal SO answers, but you get the idea how to do it now.